# Jquery DataTable Column Width Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable

I am using jquery datatable and its working fine the problem i am facing is that i have a column named `Email` inside my dataTable . Now what happens is that when some one put input into email address or anyother column like this

```
abadc@gmail.comabadc@gmail.comabadc@gmail.comabadc@gmail.comabadc@gmail.comabadc@gmail.comabadc@gmail.comabadc@gmail.comabadc@gmail.comabadc@gmail.com
```

then my DataTable look weird i know the reason that there is no space between these email address but is there any other hack like can we do it using css to force column to show multi line if it cross desired length.

Answer (score 0):

Try the CSS word-wrap property to force words to break:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

You also might need to set your table-layout to fixed for this to work:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp